# Spark: Extract field that is not always present from array of structs

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I am using Spark 3.1.2 and I have the data frame below and I want to access  the 'infos' field from every element in the array of structs. I know I can do col("arrayOfStructs.infos") but since 'infos' is not present in all elements I get a NullPointerException. Input data:

```
{
  "id": "698hyg",
  "arrayOfStructs": [
  {
        "place": "north1",
        "lock": "myLock",
        "infos": {
            "info1": "I am an info",
            "info2": "hello there"
        }
  },
  {
        "place": "north",
        "lock": "myLock"
  }]
}
```

Target output should be like this (Map the 'place' field with empty maps if 'infos' is not present):

```
{north1 -> {info1 -> I am an info, info2 -> hello there},
 north  -> {}
}
```

I am trying to use

```
map_from_arrays(col("arrayOfStructs.place"), col("arrayOfStructs.infos"))
```

but I have trouble pairing the empty/null maps because the 'infos' key is not present everywhere:

```
ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
....
```

input schema seems to be causing the issue. Ideally I would like to solve this without changing 'values' nullable to true:

```
  val schema: StructType = StructType(
StructField("id", StringType, nullable = false) ::
StructField("arrayOfStructs", ArrayType(StructType(
  StructField("place", StringType, nullable = false) ::
  StructField("lock", StringType, nullable = false) ::
  StructField("infos", MapType(StringType, StringType), nullable = false) :: Nil
  ), containsNull = false), nullable = false)
:: Nil)
```

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the error with the given example

Comment: @blackbishop Yes, I added the input schema as well which must be causing the issue

Comment: @ManosNtoulias How are you reading the data in the dataframe because if you have the data in the dataframe then the data would be in tabular format but your question shows it in json format.